# Adding sequential IDs to rows in data frame

Tags: r, rows

I have a dataset called Snapper_new that has 330 rows and each set of nine rows is named 1 through 9 as shown in the id column. I want each set of nine rows (1-9, 10-18, etc.) to have a unique ID (1,2, etc.). How would I do this in R?

[image]

Comment: Using your current ID column, `your_data$group_id = cumsum(your_data$id == 1)`.

Comment: Neat and slick solution sir :-).

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you! This worked

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach with the tidyverse

```r
library(tidyverse)

Snapper_new <- rep(seq(1:9), 3) %>% 
  enframe(name=NULL, value="id")

Snapper_new %>% 
  mutate(group_start=case_when(id==1 ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ as.numeric(0))) %>% 
  mutate(group_index=cumsum(group_start))
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#>       id group_start group_index
#>    <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1     1           1           1
#>  2     2           0           1
#>  3     3           0           1
#>  4     4           0           1
#>  5     5           0           1
#>  6     6           0           1
#>  7     7           0           1
#>  8     8           0           1
#>  9     9           0           1
#> 10     1           1           2
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Pure R answer.**

```
a = data.frame("test"=1:330, "pokus" = 1:330)
b <- unlist(lapply(1:ceiling(330/9), function(x) {replicate(9, x)}))
b <- b[1:nrow(a)]
a <- cbind(a, b)
```